# Number of possible solutions of Diophantine equations

Tags: combinatorics

I have two tasks here, where I do not understand the given answer.

$\ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 9$, where $\ x_i \in \mathbb{N}_0, 1 \le i \le 5$

The number of possible solutions answer here is $\ {9+5-1 \choose 9} = 715 $, as the set from which to choose is 5, and we choose 9 times.. or so I've being told, but I don't understand why.

Comparing this with the second task:

$\ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 9$, where $\ x_i \in \mathbb{N}, 1 \le i \le 5$

This should be rewritten as

$\ (x_1 -1) + (x_2 -1) + (x_3 -1) + (x_4-1) + (x_5 -1) = 5$

which then gives $\ { 4+5-1 \choose 4} = 70 $.

Why would I adjust the equation if the only difference is whether it is natural numbers with or without zero?

Thanks!

Comment: This type of counting is often described as the "stars and bars" counting method. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). The idea is, treat each $x_i$ as a bucket to which you want to put items. You have 9 items total. So, we have a star for each item and a bar for each division between the buckets. Since you have 5 buckets, you need 4 bars. So, it looks like this: $*********||||$. Now, every permutation of that string represents a possible solution to the original equation. $****||*|*|***$ represents $x_1=4,x_2=0,x_3=1,x_4=1,x_5=3$.

Comment: The number of permutations of 9 stars and $5-1$ bars is $\dbinom{9+5-1}{9}$

Comment: And if you want every bucket to be non-empty, you can first put one item in each bucket. This leaves 4 items, but still 5-1 bars.